# Navigating between scenes in Sprite Kit?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, skscene

Let's say I begin with a scene `initialScene`. This scene contains a few buttons. When the user taps Button A in this scene, I will present `sceneA`. So my code would look like this:

```
sceneA* scene = [[sceneA alloc] init];
[self.scene.view presentScene: scene];
```

My first question is, when an instance of `sceneA` is presented from `initialScene`, is it stacked on top of the `initialScene` instance or does it replace it? Does the instance of `initialScene` get deallocated in memory when a new scene is presented ?

I ask this because `sceneA` will have a Back Button which, when tapped, returns the user to the initial scene. Can I just create a new instance of `initialScene` within `sceneA` and present it, or will that result in multiple instances of the same scenes stacked on top of each other? Basically, can I just do this in `sceneA`?:

```
if(...) {   //if user taps back button
    initialScene* iniScene = [[initialScene alloc] init];
    [self.scene.view presentScene: iniScene];
}
```

Or is there a better way to do this? Please let me know if there is any way I can clarify this further.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Sprite Kit makes it easy to transition between scenes. You can either
>   keep scenes around persistently, or dispose of them when you
>   transition between them. In this example, you create a second scene
>   class to learn some other game behaviors. When the “Hello, World!”
>   text disappears from the screen, the code creates a new scene and
>   transitions to it. The Hello scene is discarded after the transition.

**Sprite Kit Programming Guide**

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/GettingStarted/GettingStarted.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013043-CH2-SW10